# How to sniff IP packets arriving on a particular port using C++?

Tags: sockets, networking, ipv6, packet-sniffers

I'm currently writing an application that will read the Ethernet packets send to a particular port (42557). I'm playing the pcap files from packETH tool on interface localhost (`lo`) and able to capture it on Wireshark. I have attached the screenshot of packets received in Wireshark.

Now, I want to read these packets in my C++ application. I don't know what to do. I created a IPV6 TCP/IP server that listens on port (42557) but I'm not receiving any raw packets. Am I doing something wrong here? Do I need to edit the destination IP of packets to localhost? [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to *sniff* UDP packets to port 42994 - i.e, passively receive those packets even though you're not running as a server for that port - or are you trying to *be a server* for UDP packets to port 42994, i.e. be the program to which those programs are supposed to be sent?

The two are *very* different.

If you're trying to sniff, you should use libpcap (I presume that this is Linux, as you refer to the loopback device as "lo" rather than "lo0" as it is on other UN*Xes; libpcap comes with most Linux distributions) similarly to how tcpdump, Wireshark, etc. do.  See [the DOCUMENTATION section of the tcpdump.org Web site](https://www.tcpdump.org/index.html#documentation) for some tutorials on libpcap.

You will want to capture with a filter of `udp port 42994` to capture packets to *or* from port 42994, or a filter of `udp dst port 42994` to just capture packets *to* port 42994.

If you capture on the loopback device, the packets will look like raw Ethernet packets; that will also be the case if you capture on an Ethernet device.

You can also capture on the "any" device, which captures on all network interfaces.  In that case, packets will have a ["Linux cooked"](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html) header rather than an Ethernet header.

Make sure you're getting the header you expect, by calling `pcap_datalink()` after opening the capture device, and making sure it's `DLT_EN10MB` if you're expecting Ethernet headers or `DLT_LINUX_SLL` if you're expecting "Linux cooked" headers.

If you're trying to be a server, use the standard socket APIs, and a socket with a socket type of `SOCK_DGRAM` (that's what the type should be for a UDP server) and a protocol of `IPPROTO_UDP`. You will *NOT* get raw packets; you'll get the stuff that's in the "Data" section of what Wireshark shows you.